# Get the record with the highest date from multiple columns & rows via T-SQL query or C# or Javascript/AngularJs 1

Tags: javascript, c#, sql, angularjs, t-sql

Let's say I have this MS SQL table, actually it's a result of a query that includes 5 tables:

[image]

```
ID  SOrder  Line    Date1   Date2   Date3   SomeColumn
1   123a456 10  2018-01-01  2018-01-01  2018-01-01  abc
2   123a456 10  2018-01-01  2019-01-01  2018-01-01  def
3   123a456 10  2019-01-01  2018-01-01  2020-01-01  ghi
4   123a456 10  2018-01-01  2018-01-01  2019-01-01  jkl
5   123a456 10  2018-01-01  2018-01-01  2018-01-01  mno
6   123a456 20  2018-01-01  2020-01-01  2018-01-01  prs
7   123a456 20  2019-01-01  2018-01-01  2019-01-01  tuv
8   123a456 20  2018-01-01  2018-01-01  2018-01-01  xxx
9   123a456 30  2018-01-01  2020-01-01  2018-01-01  yyy
10  123a777 10  2019-01-01  2019-01-01  2018-01-01  zzz
11  123a777 10  2020-01-01  2019-01-01  2019-01-01  111
12  123a777 20  2019-01-01  2018-01-01  2018-01-01  222
13  123a777 20  2021-01-01  2019-01-01  2019-01-01  333
14  123a777 20  2018-01-01  2018-01-01  2020-01-01  444
```

where I want to extract only the rows with ID=3,6,9,11,13 that have the highest date. So from the 1st five records that have the Line column value equal to 10, I want only the line with ID=3, because it has the highest date (2020-01-01) out of the 5.

1) How can I achieve this via T-SQL query?

2) Alternatively I could do a simple `SELECT * FROM MyTable` and do the above mentioned filtering in C# or Javascript/AngularJs 1. But how?

Comment: What have you tried? Show us your current query attempt. (BTW, most people here want formatted text, not images.)

Comment: Text table added. I have nothing useful right now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using below code you can achieve your answer.

```
CREATE TABLE #T1
(
    ID int
    ,SOrder VARCHAR(20)
    ,Line int
    ,Date1 datetime
    ,Date2 Datetime
    ,Date3 Datetime

)

;with cte as (
    SELECT ID,Line,SOrder, Date1 from #T1
    union
    SELECT ID,Line,SOrder, Date2 from #T1
    union
    SELECT ID,Line,SOrder, Date3 from #T1
)

SELECT T.* FROM #T1 T
INNER JOIN (SELECT max(Date1) as Date1,Line,SOrder FROM cte GROUP BY Line,SOrder) DT 
            ON  (DT.Date1=T.Date1 OR DT.Date1=T.Date2 OR DT.Date1=T.Date3)
            AND (DT.Line=T.Line)
            AND (DT.SOrder=T.SOrder)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would unpivot the dates using `apply`.

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by SOrder, line order by dte desc) as seqnum
      from t cross apply
           (select max(v.dte) as dte
            from values (date1), (date2), (date3)
           ) v(dte)
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

This takes the maximum date in each row and enumerates them for the lines.  The outer query chooses the latest date.

If you use `top (1) with ties`, then you don't even need the subquery:

```
select top (1) with ties t.*
from t cross apply
     (select max(v.dte) as dte
      from values (date1), (date2), (date3)
     ) v(dte)
order by row_number() over (partition by SOrder, line order by dte desc)
```